# Grouping by multiple ranges in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I tried to search for a solution, but with no success.
How can I group my table from looking like this:

```
from    |    to    |    zone
1       |    1     |      1
1       |    2     |      1
1       |    3     |      1
1       |    4     |      2
1       |    5     |      2
1       |    6     |      2
1       |    7     |      1
1       |    8     |      1
1       |    9     |      1
1       |    10    |      9
2       |    1     |      7
2       |    2     |      7
2       |    3     |      7
2       |    4     |      2
2       |    5     |      2
2       |    6     |      2
2       |    7     |      7
2       |    8     |      7
2       |    9     |      7
```

To look like this :

```
from    |    to      |    zone
1       |    1-3     |      1
1       |    4-6     |      2
1       |    7-9     |      1
1       |     10     |      9
2       |    1-3     |      7
2       |    4-6     |      2
2       |    7-9     |      7
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: what have you tried to do ? (pls post your sql query)

Comment: What's your actual data in `from` and `to`?

Comment: What are the types of all the columns in your table?

Comment: All of them are nvarchar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach here is to use the difference of row numbers method, using to `to` column as one row number, and a row number over a partition using `from` and `zone` as the other row number.  It is a bit difficult to explain why this works in so many words.  It might be best to view the demo link below to explore the query.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [from], zone ORDER BY [to]) rn
    FROM yourTable
)
SELECT
    t.[from],
    CONVERT(varchar(10), MIN(t.[to])) + '-' + CONVERT(varchar(10), MAX([to])) AS [to],
    t.zone
FROM cte t
GROUP BY
    t.[from],
    t.zone,
    t.[to] - t.rn
ORDER BY
    t.[from],
    MIN(t.[to]);
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: I answered this entire question, including setting up the demo, on a cell phone.

Comment: @st_patryk It looks like your actual data differs from what you posted in the question.  Don't do this; just tell use your real problem from the start.

Comment: Sorry for that. I am new here, but I will remember that from now on :)

Answer (score 1):

This is generally called as *Gaps and Islands* problem. If you are using `SQL Server 2012+` then

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Sum(CASE WHEN zone = prev_zone THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)OVER(partition BY [from] ORDER BY [to]) AS grp
         FROM   (SELECT *,
                        Lag(zone)OVER(partition BY [from] ORDER BY [to]) AS prev_zone
                 FROM   yourtable ) cs ([from], [to], zone)) a)
SELECT [from],
       [to] = Concat(Min([to]), '-', Max([to])),
       zone = Min(zone) 
FROM   cte
GROUP  BY [from],grp
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to use SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

```
;with mycte
AS
(
select
    ,[from]
    ,min([to]) minto
    ,max([to]) maxto
    ,[zone]
from
    mytable
group by
    [from]
    ,[zone]
)
    [from]                      AS [from]
    ,concat(minto, '-', maxto)  AS [to]
    ,[zone]                     AS [zone]
from
    mycte
```